# How to prevent incorrect messages

Tags: python

```
while True:
    question = input('Enter the secret word: ')

    if question in ['happy', 'Happy', 'HAPPY']:
        print('Great Job!')

    else:
       print('Try again!')
```

This code works but what if the user types `HaPpY`. My computer won't recognize and will say `Try again!` How do I prevent this?

Comment: Use `lower` or `upper` methods. `if question.lower() == "happy": ...`

Comment: `if question.lower() == 'happy'`

Comment: you can turn the input to lower or uppercase, then compare it with `if input.lower() == "happy"`